# Is it possible to move drives to another raspberry pi without losing data?

Tags: raspbian, linux, hard-drive

I have a raspberry pi with two external drives attached to it. For some mysterious reason it won't start anymore. It freezes during boot. (I believe it's because one of the drives accidentally was plugged out).

I have another raspberry pi lying around. What do I need to do to move the drives to the another rpi?
They are formatted in ext4 and I would like to be certain I don't use any data on them. I'm not able the dismount them in the first rpi.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: poweroff the first pi ... attach drive(s) to the second pi ... done

Comment: I had a pi with an external drive that froze on boot once - changed the `fs_passno` entry to 0 in `/etc/fstab` and the pi booted fine - there was something wrong with the drive, can't recall if it was terminal though

Answer (score 3):

First flash **Raspberry Pi OS** to a spare SD Card and boot it in the other RasPi. If it works, poweroff both RasPis, attach the two external USB drives to the other RasPi and boot it up. Now you should be able to mount the **ext4** partitions on the attached drives.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems with boot, then detach the drive(sdcard), then open that with another Linux OS with card reader. You can find the rootfs and your saved data there.